# Mocha tests are passing but assertion or expect is failing

Tags: express, mocha.js, assert

I am using `expect` and `assert` both show up as errors which is what I want and I want the test to fail. But for some reason the test passes when I use either one. I tried `expect` and then tried `assert`. Not sure why this is happening. The data I am getting back from the request is correct but it is just that assert and/or expect is not working.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../server');

describe('Unit testing the /api/auth/signup route', function () {
  it('Should return OK status', async () => {
    try {
      let res = await request(server).post('/api/auth/signup').send({
        email: 'tom@email.com',
        password: 'tompassword',
      });

      // assert.equal(res.body.data.user.email, 'josh@email.com');
      expect(res.body.data.user.email).to.equal('josh@email.com');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `assert` and `expect` throw an error (an [AssertionError](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#class-assertassertionerror) in Node) to report an unsatisfied expectation. Mocha will catch all errors thrown by the test function and report the test as failed.

You should not wrap those statements inside a try/catch block. Doing so will suppress the exception, and Mocha will consider the test as passed.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize that I wouldn't have to include the `try/catch` block in this case.